# Service or software for generating individual reports for a list of customers based on one template

Tags: pdf, reporting, mailing-list

I am looking for a service or a software that allow to prepare and send reports to customers. This is not about simple mailing software because the unique PDF file should be attached to each email.

For instance, I have a database with a list of customers and I need to send a monthly report to all of them or to any group with detailed information about this customer. The report should be prepared for each customer but has the same template.

Something like Mailing in MS Word but more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data also comes from a database, i recommend you to try DBxtra as it has a [scheduling component](http://dbxtra.com/report-scheduler.htm), the Schedule Server, which lets you send reports to a list of users, using a Email Merge job.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of software's like if you are from automation industry like mine, use [XLReporter](http://www.sytech.com/product-xlreporter-overview.asp)

If you need a general purpose tool i would recommend try using [PaperCut NG](http://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/#free)

You can schedule PDF reports for email from a simple interface

[image]

Its worth trying.